# Grant sudo rights to binary without entering password

Tags: sudo, binary

I've got some binary in /usr/bin. (*brightlight*, in my case). It changes screen brightness, but needs sudo rights to work. I want to bind it to shortkey, so I can't really enter my password every time I use it. How can I grant sudo to binary "by default", so next time I ran it it would be ran as root without entering the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to `/etc/sudoers`, replacing `<username>` with your username:

```
<username> ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/brightlight
```